# Implementing tri-state checkbox with tree control in MFC

Tags: mfc

I am new in windows programming with MFC, so I have not much knowledge about API's. I want to create a tri-state check box with a tree control.
Can anybody give me suggestion that how to create it in a very simple way. Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You Need to define your own image list with three Icons checked, unchecked, undetermined.
- Add a recursive handler to calculate the states
- Use SetItemState with INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK and LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK to set the appropriate undetermined value
- Add your own handler when the user clicks on the state icon, so that you change the Icon state

Complete description and sample code [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/multi-state-checkbox-tree-views/184416437?pgno=1).

Comment: @xMRi-Thanks a lot for giving me this suggestion. I am trying to code this. After that If I'll get problem than I'll tell you. Thank You